# DLL compile with cl.exe 136 unresolved externals

Tags: visual-studio, dll, command-line

So basically I'm trying to compile a cpp file into a dll that will be explicitly implemented

but when I run my Makefile:

```
#Build DLL in DriverApp/bin/$(IntDir)
SRC = src/DriverCore.cpp
OUT = ../DriverApp/bin/DriverCore.dll

all: $(SRC)

DLL: $(SRC)
    cl.exe $(SRC) /OUT:$(OUT) /link /DLL /NOENTRY /MACHINE:X64 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
```

I have this output :

```
PS C:\Users\ridap\Documents\GitHub\KNX-Communication-Analyser\src\Driver\DriverCore> nmake DLL

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.28.29337.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl.exe src/DriverCore.cpp /OUT:../DriverApp/bin/DriverCore.dll /link /DLL /NOENTRY /MACHINE:X64 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29337 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OU'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OT'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O:'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O.'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O.'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O/'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OD'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Or'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Ov'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oe'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Or'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OA'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Op'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Op'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O/'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Ob'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/On'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O/'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OD'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Or'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Ov'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oe'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Or'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OC'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oo'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Or'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oe'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O.'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Ol'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Ol'
DriverCore.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\ostream(746): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
src/DriverCore.cpp(28): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char *)' being compiled
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29337.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:DriverCore.exe
/DLL
/NOENTRY
/MACHINE:X64
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
DriverCore.obj
   Creating library DriverCore.lib and object DriverCore.exp
libcpmt.lib(wlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _purecall
libcpmt.lib(xlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _purecall
DriverCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _purecall
libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _purecall
libcpmt.lib(cout.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _purecall
libcpmt.lib(locale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _purecall
libcpmt.lib(xlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
DriverCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
libcpmt.lib(cout.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
libcpmt.lib(locale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
libcpmt.lib(wlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
DriverCore.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateFileA referenced in function "public: __cdecl SerialPort::SerialPort(void)" (??0SerialPort@@QEAA@XZ)
[...]
IBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol terminate referenced in function __scrt_unhandled_exception_filter
LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __current_exception referenced in function __scrt_unhandled_exception_filter
LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __current_exception_context referenced in function __scrt_unhandled_exception_filter
DriverCore.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 138 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I have already trien to add `/DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib"` but i have less unresolved symbols (98) but it still is a problem

Note: The program is compiling well on VS but when using cl.exe it fails

(I'm doing this to have a better understanding of DLL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> cl.exe $(SRC) /OUT:$(OUT) /link /DLL /NOENTRY /MACHINE:X64 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
> ```

- [`/OUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/out-output-file-name?view=msvc-160) is a linker option, not a compiler one, so it must come *after* `/link`.
- [`/NOENTRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/noentry-no-entry-point?view=msvc-160) is used for [resource-only DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-a-resource-only-dll?view=msvc-160) and prevents normal linking of the CRT.

To fix both, use the following, instead.

```
    cl.exe $(SRC) /link /OUT:$(OUT) /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
```